# Visual Studio Installer Setup Project without UAC

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

Is it possible to set up a *Visual Studio Installer - Setup* project so that the generated *Setup.msi* can be installed without requiring administrator privileges, i.e. install the app for the local user only?

All of my files are placed in the *User's Application Data Folder* and I tried to completely remove the *Application Folder* from the File System view but Visual Studio won't let me do that. I don't modify any registry settings or anything else, that would require elevated permissions.

I checked all of the properties of the *Deployment Project* node but couldn't find any setting relating to UAC.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646358/create-a-setup-for-windows-form-application-without-administrator-password-while

Answer (score 0):

don't call your setup exe "setup.exe"

or add a post build setup to slip a setup.exe.manifest file to the output folder with requestedExecutionLevel set to asInvoker. For an example check https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/reference_builds/chrome_win/+/master/setup.exe.manifest