# How to create C# application installer in Visual Studio 2022, which can be installed without administrator rights?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, windows-installer, visual-studio-2022

My problem is that, I have created an installer for my application in Visual Studio 2022 and it is asking for admin rights if I'm trying to setup it on another computer. I can only install it on another pc without admin rights.

Is it possible to make an installer which can be runnable without admin rights?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a setup for windows form application Without Administrator password while install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646358/create-a-setup-for-windows-form-application-without-administrator-password-while)

Comment: Hello, my issue still not solved, the problem with ClickOnce is that, the program is not installed fully, so it is not have a desktop icon and it's not private, so anyone can access the code. That's why I need to create an installer which do not ask for admin rights.

Comment: @VyPERaxz Hello, I don't quite understand what you mean. What is the reason why OneClick cannot meet your requirements? Can you repeat it?

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT my biggest problem is that, I work for a company and I want to place the installer file in a server where anyone can access it. With OneClick anyone can access to the source code of the programme. Also, it will not have a desktop icon, and the windows defender do not allow the program to run. I'd like to setup for each computer which will use my programme, and in one hand the user can easyli run it from the desktop with an icon, on the other hand they don't have to do the full procedure on launch. Also, they don't have admin rights on their computers.

Comment: @VyPERaxz Hi, I edited a new answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an installer generator again, such as InstallShield, Wix or NSIS. Use them to make an installer that doesn't require administrator privileges to install. These generators can create installers and set permission levels during installation so that installations do not require administrator privileges. You can integrate these generators in vs and generate installers.